# scrapy HtmlXPathSelector from a string

Tags: scrapy

I have a html response on a string.
I am trying to make a HtmlXPathSelector out of it, so that i can use xpaths on it.
But it shows,

```
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'str' obj
```

Any idea how to convert string to the response object that HtmlXPathSelector accepts?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text="my html")
```

Comment: HtmlXPathSelector is now deprecated, use sel = Selector(text="my html)